# Lodash filter function value is replacing the original array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I need to filter the Country details with lo-dash filter. Even though the filter works perfectly, it replaces the original country array which i dont want.

I am developing this in React.js. This is a filter which filters as following:

country
  country name, country meta tag,cityIds. cityIds -> name,meta tag, portIds, portIds ->name,meta tag

I have attached the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/6tttaq6c/2/

```
const country =      [{
    "_id": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
    "iso": "IN",
    "__v": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "cityIds": [{
        "_id": "59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
        "countryId": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
        "__v": 3,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [{
            "_id": "59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca",
            "cityId": "59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
            "longLat": [80.2425, 13.0595],
            "__v": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "relatedPods": [{
                "_id": "59bf7b7cdd1e5f1af51fd4f0",
                "cityId": null,
                "isDdpService": 1,
                "longLat": [72.8777, 19.076],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": ["59c4ab42841f767b0ba8065b", "59bf7b7cdd1e5f1af51fd4f0"],
                "isDoorService": 1,
                "metaTags": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "Mumbai"
                }],
                "name": "Mumbai China Port"
            }, {
                "_id": "59cd89b74f47ae1b04600fd1",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59cd88994f47ae1b04600fce",
                    "countryId": null,
                    "__v": 0,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59cd89b74f47ae1b04600fd1"],
                    "metaTags": [],
                    "name": "TestC1299"
                },
                "longLat": [20, 10],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": ["59cd8a094f47ae1b04600fd2"],
                "isDoorService": 1,
                "metaTags": [],
                "name": "TestP1299"
            }, {
                "_id": "59c4ebe5841f767b0ba806a2",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
                    "countryId": {
                        "_id": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
                        "iso": "IN",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "status": 1,
                        "cityIds": ["59b66e27424d6751ceafe98e", "59ba41aa424d6751ceafe99c", "59c3877d850f915d9715b93b", "59c3877f850f915d9715b93c", "59c38784850f915d9715b93e", "59c3878a850f915d9715b940", "59c38798850f915d9715b942", "59c38704850f915d9715b93a", "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652", "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653", "59c4aa1d841f767b0ba80654", "59c4d9a7841f767b0ba8067b", "59c4d9f6841f767b0ba8067c", "59c4df53841f767b0ba80685", "59defc134417e706e0f9fe82", "59defd0b52068d07d150ca8a", "59df4fc6ae861956765ac72b", "59e457fa27a94c49df6dc16b", "59e4656127fce563f6556f1c", "59e465ef27fce563f6556f1e", "59e469f2381f686991238c16", "59e46a56bf9d006a99e568a1", "59e46adc231f5a6c2252833e", "59e46b2a231f5a6c22528340", "59e46c2892fd5170ac3bec7f", "59e4586e4a053c4b10ae5724", "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91"],
                        "ddpServiceId": ["59ed5cb229ceca7cb1d3701a"],
                        "isDdpService": 0,
                        "usdExchangeRate": 0.015445207408516145,
                        "currency": "INR",
                        "metaTags": [{
                            "id": 1,
                            "text": "IN"
                        }, {
                            "id": 2,
                            "text": "india"
                        }],
                        "name": "India"
                    },
                    "__v": 3,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59c4a64d841f767b0ba80651", "59c4e31a841f767b0ba8068f", "59c4ebe5841f767b0ba806a2", "59dc634e196d075fa7e2a45c", "59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca", "59dc76cbcb4f3c3d00080f82", "59df14ec5a4fcc1d91201831", "59df1fcd5a4fcc1d91201866", "59df23af5a4fcc1d91201894", "59df4d154609214547e85867", "59e1e824749a8b07ac206249", "59e8a512cbfaf6752210cbce", "59e8b000cbfaf6752210cbd3", "59e8b025cbfaf6752210cbd4", "59f1cfe8b558db21a88a36f4"],
                    "metaTags": [{
                        "text": "hope",
                        "id": 1
                    }],
                    "name": "chennai"
                },
                "longLat": [80.237617, 13.067439],
                "__v": 1,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": ["59c4ec17841f767b0ba806a3"],
                "isDoorService": 1,
                "metaTags": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "TP"
                }, {
                    "text": "beach",
                    "id": 2
                }],
                "name": "beach station"
            }],
            "isDoorService": 1,
            "metaTags": [],
            "name": "chennai port"
        }, {
            "_id": "59df23af5a4fcc1d91201894",
            "cityId": "59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
            "longLat": [80.2707, 13.0827],
            "__v": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "relatedPods": [{
                "_id": "59df23e75a4fcc1d91201895",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653",
                    "countryId": {
                        "_id": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
                        "iso": "IN",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "status": 1,
                        "cityIds": ["59b66e27424d6751ceafe98e", "59ba41aa424d6751ceafe99c", "59c3877d850f915d9715b93b", "59c3877f850f915d9715b93c", "59c38784850f915d9715b93e", "59c3878a850f915d9715b940", "59c38798850f915d9715b942", "59c38704850f915d9715b93a", "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652", "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653", "59c4aa1d841f767b0ba80654", "59c4d9a7841f767b0ba8067b", "59c4d9f6841f767b0ba8067c", "59c4df53841f767b0ba80685", "59defc134417e706e0f9fe82", "59defd0b52068d07d150ca8a", "59df4fc6ae861956765ac72b", "59e457fa27a94c49df6dc16b", "59e4656127fce563f6556f1c", "59e465ef27fce563f6556f1e", "59e469f2381f686991238c16", "59e46a56bf9d006a99e568a1", "59e46adc231f5a6c2252833e", "59e46b2a231f5a6c22528340", "59e46c2892fd5170ac3bec7f", "59e4586e4a053c4b10ae5724", "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91"],
                        "ddpServiceId": ["59ed5cb229ceca7cb1d3701a"],
                        "isDdpService": 0,
                        "usdExchangeRate": 0.015445207408516145,
                        "currency": "INR",
                        "metaTags": [{
                            "id": 1,
                            "text": "IN"
                        }, {
                            "id": 2,
                            "text": "india"
                        }],
                        "name": "India"
                    },
                    "__v": 0,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59c4ab42841f767b0ba8065b", "59c4ab65841f767b0ba8065c", "59dddbb3a8dd2014c4ae04d9", "59df1ff55a4fcc1d91201867", "59df23e75a4fcc1d91201895", "59e8a371cbfaf6752210cbcb", "59e8a401cbfaf6752210cbcc"],
                    "metaTags": [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "text": "bangulure"
                    }],
                    "name": "bangulure"
                },
                "longLat": [77.580643, 12.972442],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": [],
                "isDoorService": 0,
                "metaTags": [],
                "name": "Port(Dest)"
            }, {
                "_id": "59df4d314609214547e85868",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59ccb67a4f47ae1b04600fc9",
                    "countryId": {
                        "_id": "59d782ec669d607c2add51f7",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "iso": "LK",
                        "status": 1,
                        "cityIds": ["59ccb67a4f47ae1b04600fc9"],
                        "ddpServiceId": null,
                        "isDdpService": 0,
                        "usdExchangeRate": 0.006507451116124828,
                        "currency": "LKR",
                        "metaTags": [],
                        "name": "Sri Lanka"
                    },
                    "__v": 1,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59df4d314609214547e85868", "59df1cdd5a4fcc1d91201852", "59f1bb2619e254063935ac44"],
                    "metaTags": [{
                        "text": "zz",
                        "id": 1
                    }, {
                        "text": "sricol",
                        "id": 2
                    }],
                    "name": "colomboo"
                },
                "longLat": [72.8777, 19.076],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": [],
                "isDoorService": 0,
                "metaTags": [],
                "name": "dest"
            }],
            "isDoorService": 0,
            "metaTags": [],
            "name": "Port(source)"
        }],
        "metaTags": [{
            "text": "hope",
            "id": 1
        }],
        "name": "chennai"
    }, {
        "_id": "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652",
        "countryId": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
        "__v": 0,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [{
            "_id": "59c4ec17841f767b0ba806a3",
            "cityId": "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652",
            "longLat": [80.2425, 13.0595],
            "__v": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "relatedPods": [{
                "_id": "59c4ebe5841f767b0ba806a2",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
                    "countryId": {
                        "_id": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
                        "iso": "IN",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "status": 1,
                        "cityIds": ["59b66e27424d6751ceafe98e", "59ba41aa424d6751ceafe99c", "59c3877d850f915d9715b93b", "59c3877f850f915d9715b93c", "59c38784850f915d9715b93e", "59c3878a850f915d9715b940", "59c38798850f915d9715b942", "59c38704850f915d9715b93a", "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652", "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653", "59c4aa1d841f767b0ba80654", "59c4d9a7841f767b0ba8067b", "59c4d9f6841f767b0ba8067c", "59c4df53841f767b0ba80685", "59defc134417e706e0f9fe82", "59defd0b52068d07d150ca8a", "59df4fc6ae861956765ac72b", "59e457fa27a94c49df6dc16b", "59e4656127fce563f6556f1c", "59e465ef27fce563f6556f1e", "59e469f2381f686991238c16", "59e46a56bf9d006a99e568a1", "59e46adc231f5a6c2252833e", "59e46b2a231f5a6c22528340", "59e46c2892fd5170ac3bec7f", "59e4586e4a053c4b10ae5724", "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91"],
                        "ddpServiceId": ["59ed5cb229ceca7cb1d3701a"],
                        "isDdpService": 0,
                        "usdExchangeRate": 0.015445207408516145,
                        "currency": "INR",
                        "metaTags": [{
                            "id": 1,
                            "text": "IN"
                        }, {
                            "id": 2,
                            "text": "india"
                        }],
                        "name": "India"
                    },
                    "__v": 3,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59c4a64d841f767b0ba80651", "59c4e31a841f767b0ba8068f", "59c4ebe5841f767b0ba806a2", "59dc634e196d075fa7e2a45c", "59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca", "59dc76cbcb4f3c3d00080f82", "59df14ec5a4fcc1d91201831", "59df1fcd5a4fcc1d91201866", "59df23af5a4fcc1d91201894", "59df4d154609214547e85867", "59e1e824749a8b07ac206249", "59e8a512cbfaf6752210cbce", "59e8b000cbfaf6752210cbd3", "59e8b025cbfaf6752210cbd4", "59f1cfe8b558db21a88a36f4"],
                    "metaTags": [{
                        "text": "hope",
                        "id": 1
                    }],
                    "name": "chennai"
                },
                "longLat": [80.237617, 13.067439],
                "__v": 1,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": ["59c4ec17841f767b0ba806a3"],
                "isDoorService": 1,
                "metaTags": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "TP"
                }, {
                    "text": "beach",
                    "id": 2
                }],
                "name": "beach station"
            }],
            "isDoorService": 1,
            "metaTags": [{
                "id": 1,
                "text": "Mu"
            }],
            "name": "Nungambakkam"
        }, {
            "_id": "59df13b35a4fcc1d91201829",
            "cityId": "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652",
            "longLat": [21.34, 17],
            "__v": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "relatedPods": [{
                "_id": "59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
                    "countryId": {
                        "_id": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
                        "iso": "IN",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "status": 1,
                        "cityIds": ["59b66e27424d6751ceafe98e", "59ba41aa424d6751ceafe99c", "59c3877d850f915d9715b93b", "59c3877f850f915d9715b93c", "59c38784850f915d9715b93e", "59c3878a850f915d9715b940", "59c38798850f915d9715b942", "59c38704850f915d9715b93a", "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652", "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653", "59c4aa1d841f767b0ba80654", "59c4d9a7841f767b0ba8067b", "59c4d9f6841f767b0ba8067c", "59c4df53841f767b0ba80685", "59defc134417e706e0f9fe82", "59defd0b52068d07d150ca8a", "59df4fc6ae861956765ac72b", "59e457fa27a94c49df6dc16b", "59e4656127fce563f6556f1c", "59e465ef27fce563f6556f1e", "59e469f2381f686991238c16", "59e46a56bf9d006a99e568a1", "59e46adc231f5a6c2252833e", "59e46b2a231f5a6c22528340", "59e46c2892fd5170ac3bec7f", "59e4586e4a053c4b10ae5724", "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91"],
                        "ddpServiceId": ["59ed5cb229ceca7cb1d3701a"],
                        "isDdpService": 0,
                        "usdExchangeRate": 0.015445207408516145,
                        "currency": "INR",
                        "metaTags": [{
                            "id": 1,
                            "text": "IN"
                        }, {
                            "id": 2,
                            "text": "india"
                        }],
                        "name": "India"
                    },
                    "__v": 3,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59c4a64d841f767b0ba80651", "59c4e31a841f767b0ba8068f", "59c4ebe5841f767b0ba806a2", "59dc634e196d075fa7e2a45c", "59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca", "59dc76cbcb4f3c3d00080f82", "59df14ec5a4fcc1d91201831", "59df1fcd5a4fcc1d91201866", "59df23af5a4fcc1d91201894", "59df4d154609214547e85867", "59e1e824749a8b07ac206249", "59e8a512cbfaf6752210cbce", "59e8b000cbfaf6752210cbd3", "59e8b025cbfaf6752210cbd4", "59f1cfe8b558db21a88a36f4"],
                    "metaTags": [{
                        "text": "hope",
                        "id": 1
                    }],
                    "name": "chennai"
                },
                "longLat": [80.2425, 13.0595],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": ["59bf7b7cdd1e5f1af51fd4f0", "59dc76cbcb4f3c3d00080f82", "59cd89b74f47ae1b04600fd1", "59c4ebe5841f767b0ba806a2"],
                "isDoorService": 1,
                "metaTags": [],
                "name": "chennai port"
            }],
            "isDoorService": 0,
            "metaTags": [],
            "name": "mumbai"
        }],
        "metaTags": [{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "mumbai"
        }],
        "name": "mumbai"
    }, {
        "_id": "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653",
        "countryId": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
        "__v": 0,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [],
        "metaTags": [{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "bangulure"
        }],
        "name": "bangulure"
    }, {
        "_id": "59df4fc6ae861956765ac72b",
        "countryId": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
        "__v": 0,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [],
        "metaTags": [{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "chennai"
        }],
        "name": "chennai"
    }, {
        "_id": "59e457fa27a94c49df6dc16b",
        "countryId": "59b3addf424d6751ceafe983",
        "__v": 3,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [],
        "metaTags": [{
            "text": "newbei",
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "text": "jing",
            "id": 2
        }],
        "name": "newbeijing"
    }, {
        "_id": "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91",
        "countryId": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
        "__v": 0,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [{
            "_id": "59f2c5f1beccec3b4cd51a99",
            "cityId": "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91",
            "longLat": [80.2707, 13.0827],
            "__v": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "relatedPods": [{
                "_id": "59f2c5f1beccec3b4cd51a9a",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652",
                    "countryId": {
                        "_id": "59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
                        "iso": "IN",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "status": 1,
                        "cityIds": ["59b66e27424d6751ceafe98e", "59ba41aa424d6751ceafe99c", "59c3877d850f915d9715b93b", "59c3877f850f915d9715b93c", "59c38784850f915d9715b93e", "59c3878a850f915d9715b940", "59c38798850f915d9715b942", "59c38704850f915d9715b93a", "59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652", "59c4a9d5841f767b0ba80653", "59c4aa1d841f767b0ba80654", "59c4d9a7841f767b0ba8067b", "59c4d9f6841f767b0ba8067c", "59c4df53841f767b0ba80685", "59defc134417e706e0f9fe82", "59defd0b52068d07d150ca8a", "59df4fc6ae861956765ac72b", "59e457fa27a94c49df6dc16b", "59e4656127fce563f6556f1c", "59e465ef27fce563f6556f1e", "59e469f2381f686991238c16", "59e46a56bf9d006a99e568a1", "59e46adc231f5a6c2252833e", "59e46b2a231f5a6c22528340", "59e46c2892fd5170ac3bec7f", "59e4586e4a053c4b10ae5724", "59f2c23fbeccec3b4cd51a91"],
                        "ddpServiceId": ["59ed5cb229ceca7cb1d3701a"],
                        "isDdpService": 0,
                        "usdExchangeRate": 0.015445207408516145,
                        "currency": "INR",
                        "metaTags": [{
                            "id": 1,
                            "text": "IN"
                        }, {
                            "id": 2,
                            "text": "india"
                        }],
                        "name": "India"
                    },
                    "__v": 0,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59c4aaf1841f767b0ba80659", "59c4ab03841f767b0ba8065a", "59c4ec17841f767b0ba806a3", "59df13b35a4fcc1d91201829", "59e1e813749a8b07ac206248", "59e5adf14a0803445703af8d", "59e5b52684db48454bdf7253", "59e8af17cbfaf6752210cbcf", "59e8af22cbfaf6752210cbd1", "59e8b1dacbfaf6752210cbd5", "59e8b1eecbfaf6752210cbd7", "59e8b1f1cbfaf6752210cbd9", "59e8b1fbcbfaf6752210cbdb", "59e8b2fecbfaf6752210cbde", "59f1cc0de9f7c41d9af5dfb2", "59f2c2b9beccec3b4cd51a92", "59f2c5f1beccec3b4cd51a97", "59f2c5f1beccec3b4cd51a9a"],
                    "metaTags": [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "text": "mumbai"
                    }],
                    "name": "mumbai"
                },
                "longLat": [72.8777, 19.076],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": [],
                "isDoorService": 1,
                "metaTags": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": ""
                }],
                "name": "Mumbai "
            }],
            "isDoorService": 1,
            "metaTags": [{
                "id": 1,
                "text": ""
            }],
            "name": "CHENNAI"
        }],
        "metaTags": [],
        "name": "CHENNAI"
    }],
    "ddpServiceId": ["59ed5cb229ceca7cb1d3701a"],
    "isDdpService": 0,
    "usdExchangeRate": 0.015445207408516145,
    "currency": "INR",
    "metaTags": [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "IN"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "india"
    }],
    "name": "India"
}, {
    "_id": "59d782ec669d607c2add51f7",
    "__v": 0,
    "iso": "LK",
    "status": 1,
    "cityIds": [{
        "_id": "59ccb67a4f47ae1b04600fc9",
        "countryId": "59d782ec669d607c2add51f7",
        "__v": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "portIds": [{
            "_id": "59df1cdd5a4fcc1d91201852",
            "cityId": "59ccb67a4f47ae1b04600fc9",
            "longLat": [79.843561, 6.939517],
            "__v": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "relatedPods": [{
                "_id": "59df1d485a4fcc1d91201853",
                "cityId": {
                    "_id": "59cd88a44f47ae1b04600fcf",
                    "countryId": null,
                    "__v": 0,
                    "status": 1,
                    "portIds": ["59cd8a094f47ae1b04600fd2", "59df1d485a4fcc1d91201853"],
                    "metaTags": [],
                    "name": "TestC299"
                },
                "longLat": [-158.00196, 21.479587],
                "__v": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "relatedPods": [],
                "isDoorService": 0,
                "metaTags": [],
                "name": "Hawaii"
            }],
            "isDoorService": 1,
            "metaTags": [{
                "id": 1,
                "text": "col"
            }],
            "name": "colombo"
        }],
        "metaTags": [{
            "text": "zz",
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "text": "sricol",
            "id": 2
        }],
        "name": "colomboo"
    }],
    "ddpServiceId": null,
    "isDdpService": 0,
    "usdExchangeRate": 0.006507451116124828,
    "currency": "LKR",
    "metaTags": [],
    "name": "Sri Lanka"
}]






const filterTree = (filter, list) => {
  return _.filter(list, (item) => {

  //console.log(item,"AAAA")
    if (_.includes(_.toLower(item.name), _.toLower(filter))) {
        //console.log(item,"11111")
        return true;
    }
    else if(_.findIndex( item.metaTags, function(o) { return _.includes(_.toLower(o.text), _.toLower(filter))})  >=0 ){
            return true;
    }
    else if (item.cityIds) {
        //console.log(item.cityIds,"22222")

        item.cityIds = filterTree(filter, item.cityIds);
        return !_.isEmpty(item.cityIds);
    }else if (item.portIds) {
        //console.log(item,"33333",!_.isEmpty(item.portIds))
        item.portIds = filterTree(filter, item.portIds);
        return !_.isEmpty(item.portIds);
    }
  });
};


console.log(filterTree('nungambakkam', country),"output");

console.log( country);
```

Comment: Can you simplify your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem?  I know this takes time but good questions usually take about **30 minutes** to compose.  Stack overflow is for questions and answers, not free debugging.

Comment: Filtering an array returns new array but same objects as in original array. If you modify object in filter it modifies original object in original array

Comment: @charlietfl yeah exactly, How to resolve this?any idea

Comment: @BonsaiOak i will update now

Comment: Depends what you want from it. Use `assign` if you want to copy objects